# How to get minecraft coordinates in SMP when F3 launches IE

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need coordinates for Minecraft in SMP, I know that you should press F3 but that launches IE and takes focus to IE making me unable to find coordinates. How can I find coordinates?

Comment: The  better question, as fail badp alluded to, is "Why is IE launching when I hit F3?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Psychic debugging — if your keyboard has an <kbd>F-lock</kbd> button, press it (an [F] icon should lit on your keyboard.)

Comment: Thanks but I figured it out, it was /getpos you have the best answer anyway

Comment: @ja5087 /getpos is not a vanilla command; it only works on servers that are modded to support it :)

Comment: oh i didn't know that