# How do I use F3 to get my coordinates when my laptop makes F3 a special key?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

I can't get the coordinates on my computer because it keeps changing the brightness.

I have a windows 8 Samsung, and I'm playing Minecraft version 1.6.4.

Comment: Do you have a function key on your computer? Try pressing that along with F3

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19669/how-to-get-minecraft-coordinates-in-smp-when-f3-launches-ie

Comment: There's nothing actually specific to Minecraft about this question (if the f3 key does something special on your keyboard, it presumably does so regardless of what application is being run), meaning that the question is off-topic on Arqade.

Answer (score 15):

Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. This would press the actual <kbd>F3</kbd> key, instead of your brightness key.

Comment: You can also (as I have done) change this setting because having F3 default to brightness is dumb.

Comment: @Unionhawk I have a similar laptop, and F3 gives me the actual coordinates, but neither Fn+F3 or F3 changes the brightness ._.

Comment: @JeffreyLin Fn+F3 is a different function on some computers.

Comment: @evohacker, usually a laptops 'function' key is located at the bottom left corner, usually somwehere between the [alt], [window] and [ctrl] keys.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on my old laptop. If you can't just press F3, press Fn at the same time. You can find the Fn key at the bottom of your keyboard, left side. Hope this helped :D

Answer (score -1):

Look at the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys right next to <kbd>F12</kbd>. There should be a <kbd>fn lock</kbd> key - hit that once. It worked for me and I have a Samsung Series 5 Windows 8 computer.