# I can't check my coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I press <kbd>F3</kbd>, my coordinates don't show up. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> doesn't work either.
I'm using windows 8.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use F3 to get my coordinates when my laptop makes F3 a special key?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132160/how-do-i-use-f3-to-get-my-coordinates-when-my-laptop-makes-f3-a-special-key)

Comment: But the answers provided in the suggested duplicate don't answer this question, as the OP specifically says that Fn+F3 doesn't work either.

Comment: That means the duplicate has an incomplete set of answers, not that it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>?
A friend of mine had the same error and this key combination worked for him.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have a key that shows 'FN' (Sometimes blue)?
Usually it is next to the CRTL or WINDOWS key, and if it is a special function key, you would need to hold down this FN key, then while keeping it help down, press F3