# my problem with the f1-f12 keys

Tags: roblox

so I get this problem a lot, and its because my f2-f3 keys are keybinded to letter keys. How do I unbind them? it messes me up a lot when I'm trying to play Roblox arsenal where I need to turn my volume down but it switches my weapon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use F3 to get my coordinates when my laptop makes F3 a special key?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132160/how-do-i-use-f3-to-get-my-coordinates-when-my-laptop-makes-f3-a-special-key)

Comment: Why is this closed? This is not related to fn, he wants to use the special feature but like on my computer, f1, f2, f3 also inputs a b and c respectively. "its because my f2-f3 keys are keybinded to letter keys" This is not clear?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is probably on a laptop that needs to save space, muti-bound keys tend to have a secondary key that must be held in order to use the secondary key-binding. A common example is the Shift key, but typically there is also a Windows key or Function (Fn) key that will have this behavior. On my own computers, it shows which key will be used by a corresponding color or border for one of the two icons on the key, ie: The Function key has blue lettering on it, the numbers keys have numbers in white and f#'s in blue. I have to hold the Function key while pressing the other key in order to make them use the f# key binding instead of the regular number key binding.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, function keys are bound into the BIOS/UEFI, so there really isn't a way to rebind them if you don't want to modify the BIOS/UEFI. Here's a resource to help you with rebinding your keys: https://www.howtogeek.com/235351/how-to-choose-whether-your-function-keys-are-f1-f12-keys-or-special-keys/

Comment: Hello, welcome to Arqade. I think what you can do is that you should write a brief summary of how to rebind keys, according to the article you gave. This can save the readers lots of time.

Comment: [Here are some link rules](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) (The title of the page is promotion and I know you’re not promoting anything but those rules apply here)