# How do I see ID on minecraft blocks, if I am on laptop

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I know I need to do F3+H to see the ID. But I am on my laptop which means I have a volume button on my F3.

I would use ID minecraft site but I am using modded blocks too. I'd apreciate if anyone knows how to help or is someone had the same problem

(Edit: I tried to gold Fn+F3 then click H, even hold all the buttons. I have JEI too and it does nothing)

Comment: Have you checked here? https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Controls#Java_Edition

. Otherwise, there's probably a mod like Waila or JEI that has this particular functionality.

Comment: You probably have an "Fn" key on your keyboard. Use that to press F3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use F3 to get my coordinates when my laptop makes F3 a special key?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132160/how-do-i-use-f3-to-get-my-coordinates-when-my-laptop-makes-f3-a-special-key) (per GiantTree's answer in comments)

Comment: Voting to leave open as per OP's edit: "I tried to hold Fn+F3 then click H, even hold all the buttons. ...it does nothing"

Comment: Do you have an "F lock" key? Some older keyboards prevent you from using the F3/Fn buttons unless that is toggled on.

Answer (score -2):

Press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> and then on the right the last few lines should have the ID and info about the block.