# I don't have the F3 button

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm using a lenovo chromebook and this doesn't have the F3 button. So how should I show coordinates in Minecraft?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use F3 to get my coordinates when my laptop makes F3 a special key?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132160/how-do-i-use-f3-to-get-my-coordinates-when-my-laptop-makes-f3-a-special-key)

Comment: @TimmyJim That question is about Windows 10/8, this question is about Chromebooks. Different OS, different answers. Not a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting that makes it so when you hold search, the top row keys can be treated as function keys. Search it in settings, and enable it!
By request from Expertcoder14, here is a snapshot.
[image: The arow points to the setting]

Comment: This answer would benefit from a screenshot of the settings screen where such option would be turned on.

Comment: Done.⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀