# F3 button not working in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My F3 button doesn't work in Minecraft and no I don't want to brighten me screen but the F3 button is used for opening the coordinates and a lot of other things but for some reason I press the button to do but it brightens the screen instead.

Comment: are you playing bedrock edition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use F3 to get my coordinates when my laptop makes F3 a special key?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132160/how-do-i-use-f3-to-get-my-coordinates-when-my-laptop-makes-f3-a-special-key)

Answer (score 1):

Usually I just hold function down while pressing F3 you can try this and if it doesn't work you can just try changing your controls.

Comment: THANKY U SOOOOOOOOOOO MUCH IT WORK